# CS1513 } expected Line 17

Tags: c#, bots, discord

Alright. I've looked through all of the questions on here that have this error and looked over my code at least 10 times but I just can't find the error. This is a bot for my discord server to automate it a little better. I've counted semicolons, brackets, etc, and I just can't find where the problem is. It's saying `CS1513 } expected Line 17` but I've looked and everything looks fine. My other bot is running just fine, but this one just doesn't seem to like me. Line 17 is the `{` under `public MyBot()`.

```
namespace Dexter
{
    class MyBot
    {
        DiscordClient discord;

        public MyBot()
        {
            discord = new DiscordClient(x =>
            {
                x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
                x.LogHandler = Log;
            });

            discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
            {
                await discord.Connect("inserttokenhere", TokenType.Bot);
            });
        }

        private void Log(object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it confused because you are using a public constructor on an internal class? Try changing the constructor to internal or the class declaration to public

Comment: @ojf No, that should not be a problem.

Comment: Show us all the lines, all 17 above the line with the problem. The root cause may very well hide in there.

Comment: What's posted here is indeed balanced in terms of brackets, so it's another chunk of code responsible - whether that's the lines above or completely misidentified the error location, can't say as of yet.